# when if statement is true code goes to else?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
if (_this.tiles["suz:SuzukiHubResponse"]["suz:categories"][category][aspect]["suz:image"][imageNo] != undefined) {
    if (imageNo > (_this.tiles["suz:SuzukiHubResponse"]["suz:categories"][category][aspect]["suz:image"].length - 1)) {
        imageNo = 0;
        _this.categoriesCurrentImage[categoryIndex] = imageNo;
    }
    var img = _this.tiles["suz:SuzukiHubResponse"]["suz:categories"][category][aspect]["suz:image"][imageNo];

    _this.showImage(img, divId);
    _this.categoriesCurrentImage[categoryIndex]++;
    _this.categoryIndex++;
} else {

    if (imageNo > (_this.tiles["suz:SuzukiHubResponse"]["suz:categories"][category][aspect]["suz:image"].length - 1)) {
        imageNo = 0;
        _this.categoriesCurrentImage[categoryIndex] = imageNo;
    }

    var img = _this.tiles["suz:SuzukiHubResponse"]["suz:categories"][category][aspect]["suz:image"];
    _this.showImage(img, divId);
    _this.categoriesCurrentImage[categoryIndex]++;
    _this.categoryIndex++;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why.

i end up in the else clause even though the if is true?
It makes absolutely no sense to me.

If there is more than 1 image underneath the suz:image node it should fall into the else.
it does 99% of the time.

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted. Fix this and the bug should become more readily apparent.

Comment: use some more variables to make your code easier to read and to debug. Eg, put var img = _this.tiles["suz:SuzukiHubResponse"]["suz:categories"][category][aspect]["suz:image"]; higher up and use it within the appropriate if tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `undefined` in quotes:

```
!= "undefined"
```

Comment: Putting undefined in quotes is not required the way this is being used.  It only needs to be in quotes when it's the result of `typeof`.  Otherwise, it doesn't have quotes.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined for more info.

Comment: can someone explain to me why putting this all in a variable did the trick? i put most of the json structure into a variable named img. and now it works.